Pricing zero coupon bonds through PDE
I'm currently studying Paul Wilmott on quantitative finance and saw an interesting idea for an interest rate model that went unexplored in the book.
The idea is to model the market price of risk as a stochastic variable and then ending up with a “market price of market price of risk risk”.
I want to price a zero coupon bond with maturity $T$, and I have the following model
$$ dr = \alpha dt + \beta dB_t$$ and
$$ d\lambda = p dt + q dW_t.$$
I chose to model the “market price of market price of risk risk” by $\lambda$ itself as suggested by Paul Wilmott in this article.
This pricing scheme gives rise to the following backward PDE, to be solved for $P: \mathbb R^2 \times [0, T] \to \mathbb R$:
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2} \beta^2 \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2}  + \rho \beta q \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x \partial y} + \frac{1}{2} q^2 \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2} + (\alpha - y\beta) \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} + (x - yq) \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} - xP = 0,$$
subject to the endpoint boundary condition $P(x, y, T)=1$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb R$. The initial condition at $t = 0$ is left free. Here $\rho, p, q, \beta$ are real valued constants, and $-1 \leq \rho \leq 1$.
How do I go about numerically solving this PDE? I was thinking finite difference (unsure how this works exactly) but I am still a beginner and would like some pointers as to what is the best way to tackle this problem.
Thank you very much for reading me.

Hi, welcome to MO! What specifically do you mean by solving the PDE? It may not be possible to obtain an exact form for the solution.

@NateRiver sorry if i wasn't clear, I want to solve the PDE numerically. I was thinking about a finite difference scheme but i am not sure how to procede.

Thanks for the clarification, I understand what you’re asking now. What you have is a second order nonlinear parabolic PDE, for which numerical schemes do exist. Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with numerical analysis to tell if any of the currently known methods work on this particular equation. I’ll ask some numerical analysis people when I am able to.

Meanwhile, it might be easier to get help here if you would allow me to make some edits to the post to make it more accessible for a general audience of mathematicians. Some other choice of notation might be easier to understand for non-finance/stochastic people. I leave it up to you though!

@NateRiver Thank uou for your help. How can I add you as an editor ?

Oh you don’t have to do anything, long time users are allowed to edit posts for clarity etc. But I usually like to ask for permission and clarification before making edits.

You have my permissuon to edit my post as you see fit. Thanks again

I think your equation is essentially an advection diffusion equation, and a lot is known about them, (but not by me), and is linear with variable coefficients.
